# How to get the result of installation intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, installation, apk

In my application I download an apk from a server and save it on the device. This apk is used to update the app. If the download is finished the user is prompted to do so by using the following code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", updateAPK);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
    intent.setData(apkUri);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(intent);

} else {
    Uri apkUri = Uri.fromFile(updateAPK);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is working like it should, but my question is: Is ist possible to get the result of the intent, so I can check whether the user cancelled the installation or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Divide your scenario into three scenarios, not two.

On devices older than API Level 14, use `ACTION_VIEW` with a `file` `Uri`. Note that you do not need `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` — or, more accurately, you should be consistent in either using it or not using it across all three scenarios.

On devices that are API Level 14-23, use `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE` with a `file` `Uri`. [Set `EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT) to `true`, and use `startActivityForResult()`.

On devices that are API Level 24+, use `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE` with a `content` `Uri`, as you are doing. [Set `EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT) to `true`, and use `startActivityForResult()`.

In those latter two scenarios, `onActivityResult()` will report whether the user installed the app (`RESULT_OK`) or not.

Comment: Okay thank you for the explanation. I've read various things about this issue, but none of this seemed really clear to me. I will give it a try and mark your answer as correct if I get it working.

Comment: @Bautzi89: I failed to mention that you can only find out if the user installed or not on API Level 14+, where you can use `EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT`. Also, IIRC, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `startActivityForResult()` are incompatible.

Comment: This is correct, but the App is targetted for higher SDK versions anyway. I do receive a result when the user cancels the update (which is what I want - so I marked your answer as correct) but when I don't use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK the app updates, but then closes without an option to reopen it. So this is the next topic I will try to figure out...

Comment: @Bautzi89, did you find a way to show the dialog when not using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK ?