# Getting result from startActivityForResult inside BroadcastReciever, calling ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, apk

I am creating an app from which the user can download other apps and install them. Right now it works fine, but It does not delete the `apk` after the installation. I have tried using `BroadcastRecievers` but they do not seem to understand when the application is already installed.

At the moment I am trying to `startActivityForResult` and once that is finished, delete the `apk` from `Files`.

```
public class Updater {
    private static BroadcastReceiver onDownloadComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Logger.d("Download completed.");
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath(), downloadApp.getDownloadKey());
            Logger.i("Opening: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

            Intent openDownloadIntent = getOpenDownloadedApkIntent(context, file);

            RelativeLayout progressView = progressViewReference.get();
            if (progressView!= null) {
                progressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            try {
                ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(openDownloadIntent, getResultCode());


            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO: more robust error handling (show dialog or something)
                Logger.e("Exception when launching download intent, message:" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    private static Intent getOpenDownloadedApkIntent(Context context, File file) {

        // The type of intent to use to open the downloaded apk changed in Android N (7.0)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                    context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".utils.DownloadedFileProvider",
                    file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.setData(path);
            return intent;
        } else {
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            return intent;
        }
    }
}
```

So I have the `Updater` class where the 2 methods are (see my code above). And this class is being called by an adapter, so there is nowhere to put the `onActivityResult`. I tried placing it in the `Activity` that calls the `Adapter`, which calls the `Updater` class but it does not reach there even with the `EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT`

So my question is.. how can I call `onActivityResult` here once the installation is finished.

Comment: onActiverResult is method which you override in Activity class and inside it you can check if data which come back are what you expecting. in here you have very good written example how onActivityResult works and how use it. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: I think I understand `onActivityResult` properly but the question is that since I am creating a new Intent with `Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE` I cant really call `onActivityResult` inside there or can I? Or where should I call the `onActivityResult` since these methods are not inside an activity.

Comment: so you can start acivityforresult for installation and in OnActivityResult when that get loaded and installation finish you can start ActivityForResult for deleting action and in the same ActivityforResult handle the deletion. If I understand you question properly.

Comment: Well thats the idea and the way I want to do it. But where in this code would you put the `onActivityResult`. The methods `onDownloadComplete` and `getOpenDownloadedApkIntent` are not inside an activity. Also I cannot put it inside some activity since the `Intent` is created inside `getOpenDownloadedApkIntent`

Answer (score 0):

this is pseudo code for you activity

```java
class DownloadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  // some of your code here

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
// in here you are checking if requestCode is equal to Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE
   if(requestCode == Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE and resultCode == ResultCode.OK) {
     // Start activity for deleting file
    startActivityForResult(Intente.ACTION_DELETE);
   }

  if(requestCode == Intent.ACTION_DELETE and resultCode == ResultCode.OK) {
     // Handling actions after deleted
   } 
  }
}
```

OnActivityResult is called by android, when action is ended. You do not have to call this method only inside this method you define what have to be done.

Where those onDownloadComplete and getOpenDownloadedApkIntent are defined and called?

Comment: Tried but it did not recieve anything sadly

Comment: you mean the 'data' Intent is null?

Comment: I mean it never even gets there.. to the `onActivityResult`.

Comment: which post do you mean

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207547/how-to-get-the-result-of-installation-intent this one

Comment: So I have the `Updater` class where the 2 methods are (see my code above). And this class is being called by an adapter, so there is nowhere to put the `onActivityResult`. It has been my problem since the beginning. I tried placing it in the `Activity` that calls the `Adapter`, which calls the `Updater` class but it does not reach there even with the `EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT`